# passwordNext button click for Gmail

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gmail

The passwordNext button click for gmail does not always work. Explicit wait does not seem to help either.

```
public void funcLogin() {      
    driver.findElement(LoginMail).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("email"));
    driver.findElement(LoginMail).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(PwdMail).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("passwd"));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Error:

> `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div role="button" id="passwordNext" class="O0WRkf zZhnYe e3Duub C0oVfc nDKKZc DL0QTb" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;" jsshadow="" jsname="Njthtb" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">...</div> is not clickable at point (787, 340). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ANuIbb IdAqtf" jsname="k4HEge" tabindex="0"></div>`

Comment: You don't have to rewrite implicit wait everytime, once it's written it will be applied whoever you call `findElement` method

Comment: where have you written code for explicit wait ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use explicit wait properly in order to use the functionality :
Here is code for **Gmail** login which is working fine :

**Code**

```
public class QQ_TT {

    static WebDriver driver;
    static WebDriverWait wait;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50); 
            driver.manage().window().maximize();    
            driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("headingText"))));
            driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("QQ_TT@gmail.com");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']")).click();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("headingText"))));
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("qq_tt@stackoverflow");
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']")));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']")));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']")).click();

        }

    }
```

Please let me know if you have any concerns related to this.

Comment: Glad ! I could help !